# Custom field - got multiple values for keyword argument 'related_name'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

I'm working on a custom field that is just a shortcut to `ForeignKey` that points to `addresses.Country` model.

When I run `makemigrations` it returns this error with I'm not sure:

```
TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field rsft_country on properties.Property: django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey.__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'to'
```

I understand that there are two `to` arguments passed but I don't understand why. It looks like the field is initialized two times. Once with the `kwargs` I provided and then with all the kwargs.

```
class RsftCountryField(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        kwargs['verbose_name'] = verbose_name or 'Krajina'
        to = 'addresses.Country'
        on_delete = kwargs.pop('on_delete',None) or models.PROTECT
        related_name = kwargs.pop('related_name',None) or '+'
        super().__init__(to, on_delete, related_name=related_name, related_query_name=None,
                         limit_choices_to=None, parent_link=False, to_field=None,
                         db_constraint=True, **kwargs)
```

Model:

```
...
rsft_country = addresses_fields.RsftCountryField(null=True, blank=True)
```

It prints `kwargs` two times:

```
{'null': True, 'blank': True}
{'blank': True, 'null': True, 'related_name': '+', 'on_delete': <function PROTECT at 0x7fa9fa277d00>, 'to': 'addresses.country'}
```

Why does it do that and how to make it work?

EDIT:

Basically, I just want to provide all the fields by default without having to specify it everytime I define the `country` field in model.

Comment: You should pop the `to` field out of the `destruct` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the [**`.deconstruct()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction), since that will :

```
class RsftCountryField(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['verbose_name'] = verbose_name or 'Krajina'
        to = 'addresses.Country'
        on_delete = kwargs.pop('on_delete',None) or models.PROTECT
        related_name = kwargs.pop('related_name', None) or '+'
        super().__init__(
            to,
            on_delete,
            related_name=related_name,
            related_query_name=None,
            limit_choices_to=None,
            parent_link=False,
            to_field=None,
            db_constraint=True,
            **kwargs
        )

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs.pop('to', None)
        kwargs.pop('related_query_name', None)
        kwargs.pop('limit_choices_to', None)
        kwargs.pop('parent_link', None)
        kwargs.pop('to_field', None)
        kwargs.pop('db_constraint', None)
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

You will need to make new migrations where a `RsftCountryField` is involved.

Comment: Thanks, tested and it still says: `TypeError: ForeignKey.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'to'`. I checked that and it's true. It is in kwargs and also as an `to = '...'` argument.

Comment: @Milano: did you remove the migrations where the `RsftCountryField` was involved?

Comment: Oh, right. Now it says: `TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field rlsft_country on properties.Property: 'tuple' object does not support item deletion`.

It's because `deconstruct` returns a tuple (probably arg, arg, arg, kwargs). So I'll try to modify the deconstruct.

Comment: @Milano: ah yes. I made a mistake. See update.

Comment: Thanks, now it says `del kwargs['related_query_name']
KeyError: 'related_query_name'`. Maybe this for any kwarg would help: `if 'related_query_name' in kwargs.keys(): del kwargs['related_query_name']`

Comment: @Milano: you can use `pop` to only remove the item if it is in the dictionary.

Comment: Ah, right, I thought it'd raise some Exception.